# Compiling C# code with Windows Forms in Linux

Tags: c#, linux, mono, gmcs

I downloaded a few source codes containing C# code that uses windows forms. Is it possible to compile the codes under the Linux environment (Ubuntu 12.04) and run it?

I already tried successfully to compile a few C# source codes with *mcs* and run the resulting *exe* file with *mono*.

The source codes can be downloaded [here](http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1028/). If it's possible please describe how would you compile and run *chapter 2/OpeningDocument* solution.

```
$ mcs Program.cs 
Program.cs(3,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Windows' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings
```

EDIT

```
$ gmcs -pkg:dotnet Program.cs 
Program.cs(17,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Form1' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
Program.cs(17,25): error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form)' has some invalid arguments
/usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Program.cs(17,25): error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `object' expression to type `System.Windows.Forms.Form'
Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. Works just the same as the rest. `mcs` and you're done. Why ask if you haven't tried?

Comment: Well the error seems pretty obvious: you are missing assembly references.

Comment: Mono does not support WPF applications.  The zip file you linked to also would not open.

Comment: @Ramhound The zip file is OK. Cicada answer works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not using the latest version of Mono, this should work:

```
gmcs -pkg:dotnet *.cs
```

The latest version of mono uses `mcs` instead of `gmcs`. In the previous ones, `mcs` targets .NET 1.1.

Comment: You are not compiling `Form1.cs`. Replace `Program.cs` with `*.cs` to compile all your C# code, else just write the list of files to compile.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm just starting with it, so I'm rather asking first if it has even sense.

Comment: @user7236293 Does the Mono Compiler Recognize all the needed files like the config file,the Form1.Designer.cs etc if i use the approach you have mentioned

Comment: Just in case: On CentOS 7 I faced the same problem. After installation of package mono-data-oracle it worked as shown.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to run your code against the mono migration analyser to see what fails or isn't supported. You can find the tool here: http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA. **NOTE** For the tool to work you will need access to a windows machine.

You can also take a look at current mono compatibility with various .Net features at http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility.

Specifically for windows forms see: http://www.mono-project.com/WinForms

Hope this helps.